# How to handle app links on different activities?

Tags: android, intentfilter

I have, say, domain `example.com`. It can work with both `https` and `http`. And I have Android client for this service. I want client to be able to open several link types. Here they are:

```
http://example.com
https://example.com
http://example.com/app
https://example.com/app
```

These four should be opened on the ListActivity. But also there are another links like:

```
https://testask.com/i/__some_guid__
https://testask.com/item/__some_guid__
and relevant link without https
```

They should be opened on another activity, say, DetailsActivity. Currently I have following intent filter for DetailsActivity:

```
<intent-filter
    android:autoVerify="true"
    tools:targetApi="m">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

    <data android:scheme="http" />
    <data android:scheme="https" />
    <data
         android:host="@string/root_host_endpoint"
         android:pathPattern="/i/.*" />
    <data
         android:host="@string/root_host_endpoint"
         android:pathPattern="/item/.*" />
</intent-filter>
```

And looks like it works correctly. But I don't understand, how to add MainActivity intent filter to point on root host url and not to overlap DetailsActivity intent filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welp, after some experiments I found that following intent filter is working as expected:

```
        <intent-filter
            android:autoVerify="true"
            tools:targetApi="m">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data android:scheme="http" />
            <data android:scheme="https" />
            <data android:host="@string/root_host_endpoint" />
            <data
                android:host="@string/root_host_endpoint"
                android:path="/" />
            <data
                android:host="@string/root_host_endpoint"
                android:path="/app" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have multiple activities with different intent filters. You can differentiate your intent filters using Action/Category/Data. In your case, you have to tweak your Data configuration to have it handle different intents. So MainActivity/ListActivity will have a different Data configuration as opposed to DetailsActivity

Comment: Thanks, I understand it, I just didn't get how to write it in xml.

Answer (score 0):

```
<activity android:name=".ListActivity">
<intent-filter
android:autoVerify="true"
tools:targetApi="m">
<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

<data android:scheme="http" />
<data android:scheme="https" />
<data
     android:host="example.com"
     android:pathPattern="/*/.*" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>

<activity android:name=".DetailsActivity">
<intent-filter
android:autoVerify="true"
tools:targetApi="m">
<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

<data android:scheme="http" />
<data android:scheme="https" />
<data
     android:host="@string/root_host_endpoint"
     android:pathPattern="/i/.*" />
<data
     android:host="@string/root_host_endpoint"
     android:pathPattern="/item/.*" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't handle link links
http://example.com
https://example.com
http://example.com/app
https://example.com/app

Comment: add <data
                android:host="example.com"
                android:path="/app" />